# Repair normals on possibly bad .stl files

Tags: javascript, c++, three.js, vtk, stl-format

I am new to Three.js and have been assigned the task of trying to repair the normals on files that have been coming in occasionally that appear to be bad. We do not know if they are bad scans or possibly bad uploads. We are looking into the upload function, but also would like to try and repair them if possible. Can anyone provide any ideas or tips to repair the file or find the correct normals?

Below is the code where we grab the normals and how we grab them. NOTE: this code works fine generally, it is only a problem when the normals are bad. I am also attaching one of the files so you can see the types of normals and "bad file" I am dealing with. [Get File here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6D_IBF2VNxWDAzOEE0dW9xbWs/view?usp=sharing)

We are also using VTK on the backend with C++, so a solution or idea using either of these is helpful.

```
my.geometry = geometry;

    var front = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
    {color: 0xe2e4dc, shininess: 50, side: THREE.DoubleSide});

var mesh = [new THREE.Mesh(geometry, front)];

my.scene.add(mesh[0]);
my.objects.push(mesh[0]);

var rc = new THREE.Raycaster();

var modelData = {'objects': [mesh[0].id], 'id': mesh[0].id};

var normalFound = false;
for (var dy = 80; dy >= -80; dy = dy - 10) {
  console.log('finding a normal on', 0, dy, -200);
  rc.set(new THREE.Vector3(0, dy, -200), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1));

  var hit = rc.intersectObjects([mesh[0]]);

  if (hit.length) {
    my.normal = hit[0].face.normal.normalize();
    console.log('normal', my.normal.z);

    modelData['normal'] = my.normal;

    if ((my.normal.z > 0.9 && my.normal.z < 1.1)) {
      my.requireOrienteering = true;
      modelData['arch'] = 'lower';
      normalFound = true;
      console.log('we have a lower arch');
    } else if ((my.normal.z < -0.9 && my.normal.z > -1.1)) {
      modelData['arch'] = 'upper';
      normalFound = true;
      console.log('we have an upper arch');
      }

    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it's done, but there are many existing programs that will repair .stl files for you.  Get the source code for one of them and look at it, it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the normals is an easy step. If you calculate the cross product of two vectors (geometrical one), you will get a vector, that is orthogonal to the two, you input. All you have to do now is normalize it, since normals should be normalised to not mess up lightning calculations.

For smooth surfaces, you have to calculate all normals on the point and average them. For flat surfaces each vertex has multiple normales (one for each surface).

In pseudo code it will look like this for quads:

```
foreach quad : mesh
foreach vertex : quad
    vector1 = neighborVertex.pos - vertex.pos;
    vector2 = otherNeighborVertex.pos - vertex.pos;
    vertex.normal = normalize(cross(vector1, vector2));
end foreach;
end foreach;
```

Answer (score 0):

VTK has a filter named [vtkPolyDataNormals](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataNormals.html) that you can run on your file to compute normals. You probably want to call `ConsistencyOn()`, `NonManifoldTraversalOn()`, and `AutoOrientNormalsOn()` before running it.

If you want point-normals (instead of per-cell normals) and your shape has sharp corners, you probably want to provide a feature angle with `SetFeatureAngle()` and call `SplittingOn()`.